# How do I find the volume of a parallelepiped given 4 vertices?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, volume

"Find the volume of the parallelepiped by four vertices: $(0,1,0), (2,2,2), (0,3,0),$ and $(3,1,2)$.

I know the formula to find this volume is: $|\vec{a} \circ(\vec{b}\times \vec{c})|$, and I know how to carry out the computation to get the actual value. What I need to know is the process of how I set up the values of the vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b},$ and $\vec{c}$ using the given points?

Comment: Form three difference  vectors at a vertex and find scalar triple product ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The volume of a parallelepiped determined by the vectors a, b ,c (where a, b and c share the same initial point) is the magnitude of their scalar triple product:

Take four points as $P=(0,1,0),Q=(2,2,2),R=(0,3,0),S=(3,1,2)$ and find 
$$PQ=a=\langle2-0,2-1,2-0\rangle=\langle2,1,2\rangle$$
$$PR=b=\langle0-0,3-1,0-0\rangle=\langle0,2,0\rangle$$
$$PS=c=\langle3-0,1-1,2-0\rangle=\langle3,0,2\rangle$$
Then find $|a\cdot(b\times c)|$

Comment: Thanks, this is great, but can you just elaborate a bit about PQ, PR, PS, i.e. why you chose them the way you did,  what they represent, and would it matter if we arranged them in a different pairing (such as QR, QS, etc.).

Comment: @Jaigus Yes, you can rearrange in any manner like $QR,QS$. Since the volume is determined by vectors, we first find the distance between any two points to get the vectors $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 3):

Translate the parallelepiped such that one of the vertices is the origin. Then the volume has not changed and you can use your formula.